# Using sed with an array to search for a string plus whitespace

Tags: linux, bash, sed, whitespace

I'm using sed to replace many lines in several files and I've run into a problem. I use an array to give sed many commands but need to include a couple spaces in the search to prevent sed form finding and deleting too many lines.
code:

```
( IFS='|'; sed -rie "/  ${points_r[*]};/d" io_points.dat4; )
```

The two spaces and ";" are to help avoid deleting lines I don't need to delete. Those lines were deleted, so I tried this as well:

```
( IFS='|'; sed -rie "/\s\{2,\}${points_r[*]};/d" io_points.dat4; )
```

My bash version is 3.2.25 and sed version is 4.1.5. How can I search for matches using this array, but include spaces (and ';') in the search? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: sample input

```
  2;  14; 1;I;   0;  1;  0;  66
  3;  14; 1;I;   0;  1;  0;  141
  4;  14; 1;I;   0;  1;  0;  23
  5;  14; 1;I;   0;  1;  0;  26
  7;  14; 1;I;   0;  1;  0;   0
```

points_r contains the numbers 3 4 and 5, I need to delete the lines which contain 3; 4; and 5; (first column) but not 2; or 7; (they contain a 4 in the second column)

Output would be:

```
2;  14; 1;I;   0;  1;  0;  66
7;  14; 1;I;   0;  1;  0;   0
```

Comment: You are way beyond what sed is good for. Just post some sample input and expected output to get a simple awk script that does what you want.

Comment: I edited the question to include input and output!

Comment: I thought I was following you until I saw the text `(they contain a 4 in the second column)`. Best I can tell your input file is separated by either `;`s or by `spaces-and-;`s so then the second clum of every line is `14` and so contains a 4. Can you clarify what you meant by that statement and what character(s) separate your `column`s? Also, why are the numbers you're interested in stored in an array - any particular reason for that vs in a string?

Comment: The columns are separated by a 2-4 spaces and a semi colon. I guess there is no particular reason I used an array vs a string. The array is built with a series of nested for loops to add each value. When deleting lines with sed I tried to include 2 spaces in the search criteria such that when searching the first line a "4" would not be a match, even though the array includes the number 4, it would require "  4;" in order to delete the line ("4;" would fail). I hope that helps clarify the situation. I did find a work around which I'll post in a second (out of chars here) Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Unless I misunderstood the requirements then simply do:

```
$ awk '/^[27];/' file
2;  14; 1;I;   0;  1;  0;  66
7;  14; 1;I;   0;  1;  0;   0
```

Or with `sed`:

```
$ sed '/^[27];/!d' file
2;  14; 1;I;   0;  1;  0;  66
7;  14; 1;I;   0;  1;  0;   0
```

In fact if this is the case you just want `grep`:

```
$ grep '^[27];' file
2;  14; 1;I;   0;  1;  0;  66
7;  14; 1;I;   0;  1;  0;   0
```

Comment: I think the problem is that he wants to delete all the ids in the points_r array, not necessarily just 2 and 7.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In this particular case I think this would work. The problem is that I have the same problem when doing a similar operation with 5 other arrays on 5 other files. A couple of the arrays are 600+ elements long and are editing files that are thousands of lines long. It wouldn't be practical to try to hard code in an escape for everything I want to avoid.

Comment: @user2690569 then please edit your question to show clearly a simply example using an shell array containing the patterns. That is show what the array contains (structure, values), and a matching input file and an expected output describing how the information in the array maps to the file transformation you need.

Comment: The array is essentially:
'points_r=(3 4 5)'
There is a sample input and output posted, which are the same file as I'm editing inline. The array appended in nested for loops with points_r+=($b), but I've found I can do points_r+=("  $b;") and then not worry about the spaces in the sed command. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want the values to be in an array, try this script

```
$ echo "${points_r[@]}"
2 3 4

$ awk -F'[ ;]+' -v p="${points_r[*]}" 'BEGIN{split(p,a," ");for (i in a) b[a[i]]=1}!($2 in b)' file
  2;  14; 1;I;   0;  1;  0;  66
  7;  14; 1;I;   0;  1;  0;   0
```

Note that this will only work with singe word array elements.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I haven't been able to get this to work, but its my first time trying awk so I'm likely doing something wrong. I did find a work around by adding the spaces I need to the array, instead of just the number.

Answer (score 1):

Great script!

The problem is with using the pipe, and also with the array variable.

The 3.2 shell expands these a little differently.

assign the array to a different variable so that you don't have to do array expansion in the sed command (maybe not necessary, but makes things easier):

```
arr=$points_r[*]
```

Now  do a shell substitution on the 'arr' variable to get the pipes in:

```
arr2="${arr// /|}"
```

Then use what you have, it's cool.

My shell prompt is ">>> ", and I unset IFS and OFS before this worked; for some reason they were pipes....

```
>>> x="${points_r[*]}"
>>> echo $x
3 4 5
>>> y="${x// /|}"
>>> echo $y
3|4|5
```

run the sed command with $y.

(The IFS won't be passed along to sed, I think. It receives 3 4 5 )

For the sed line you used, you need to enclose the regexp in () so it is one match group, (3 or 4 or 5)

```
sed -re "/  (${y});/d" io_points.dat4;
  2;  14; 1;I;   0;  1;  0;  66
  7;  14; 1;I;   0;  1;  0;   0
```

I haven't used the 'i' switch...